# Python script (for sound) doesn't start on boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, raspbian

I have an issue.

my project is about to view streaming video and control motors or sound by web page (on local IP). I am using Raspberry PI Web Camera Interface. My python scripts only run when click the button (The buttons are on the web page). My sound button works well when I run my script on thonny or terminal but it doesn't work on boot.

Here is my code; ses.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import time,sys
import subprocess

button = Button(21) # This button is not button on the web page

def play_music():
    subprocess.run(["mpg321"],"/home/pi/003.mp3"])
    subprocess.run('raspi-gpio set 21 op dh',shell=True)

try:
    button.when_pressed = play_music
    pause()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

By the way buttons which is on the web page run .sh file and this .sh file run the python scripts

I write `sudo python3 /home/pi/ses.py & > /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1` in `/etc/rc.local` to start on boot.
the log file is empty.

My web gui is here, i have no real button. the buttons what i write about is on this photo. a .sh file run When i click the Ses-2 button, and this .sh file run my ses.py
[image]

Comment: how do you know if play_music is called? put a print to a log file in that function to make sure is being executed.

Comment: you are right, i put the print and log file is still empty so my script doesnt work on boot.

Comment: Did you mean: `button.when_pressed = play_music()`?

Comment: the script doesnt start, not only this line '' button.when_pressed = play_music() ''

Comment: Is your question about why the script does not start on boot or about why a function is not called when you press the button on pin 21? If you manually start the script does the button work?

Comment: thanks for your reply i edited my post. if i manually run my python script so my system works fine. i have no real button on pin21, pin21 is low when i click my ses-2 button so the python script play the sound , pin21 is being high if sound is stop so i can run the sound again next time. my question is ' Why the script does not start on boot. '

Answer (score 1):

> I write sudo python3 /home/pi/ses.py & > /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1 in /etc/rc.local to start on boot.

I guess you did not get that memo, but `rc.local` has been *deprecated* for a few years now. I *think* you may still be able to use it, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth... but here's [a guide to help you get started](https://mox.sh/sysadmin/rc-local-deprecated/) if you're determined to use it.

*N.B. This answer uses the CLI/terminal, so if you're not comfortable with that, you can stop reading now.*

Other than `rc.local` you have two other *mainstream* alternatives for starting your script:

1. [create a `systemd` "unit"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=create+systemd+unit)
2. use [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

---

`cron` is generally easier than `systemd`. I'm all about instant gratification, so let's use that:

- a `cron job` is typically one single line in your `crontab` file. That line includes a ***schedule***, and a ***command***. `cron` runs your *command* at the *schedule*d time - pretty straightforward.
- to create your `cron job`, you must edit your `crontab` file. This is done like so:

```bash
$ crontab -e
```

- when you open your `crontab` for the first time the system will prompt you to select an editor. If you're unsure which one to use, choose `nano` (`pico`?)
- if you need `root` privileges (and it seems you do) to run your Python script, you should open `root`'s `crontab`; the only thing to remember w/ scripts run by `cron` is **do not use `sudo` in your script**.:

```bash
$ sudo crontab
```

- let's set up the ***schedule :***

In your `crontab` editor, enter the following at the bottom of the `crontab`... the `@reboot` schedule will cause your command to be executed each time your RPi is booted.

```
@reboot
```

- now that you've completed the ***schedule***, let's enter the ***command***:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/ses.py > /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1
```

- save your `crontab` & exit the editor; you are ready to test:

```bash
$ sudo reboot
```

---

##### Some other things:

- `cron` has some *shortcomings* relative to `systemd`. One is that `cron` does not know whether or not all of the *resources* needed to execute your script are ready when it is started (`cron` is actually started by `systemd`, but that's a longer story).

  If you see any evidence in your `/home/pi/Desktop/log.txt` file that a resource was unavailable when `cron` tried to run it, the solution is simple: `sleep`. Edit your `cron job` to sleep a while before running the command:

```
@reboot sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/ses.py > /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1
```

- another *"shortcoming"* is that `cron` does ***not*** run your jobs in the same ***environment*** that you have in your login or interactive shell. This can cause some *surprises*, but a bit of diligence in using **full path specifications** will generally keep things on track.
- finally, note that I have removed your `&` background invocation in your command. I did this because all `cron jobs` run in the background... however, I'm not familiar with your application so *other adjustments* may be required.

So - that's it - end of answer... look forward to hearing your feedback.

Comment: the script worked but still doesnt play sound

Comment: @fatih_koca: have you looked in your `/home/pi/Desktop/log.txt` file. While you're troubleshooting, it might be best to use the "append" form of the redirect (`>>`) instead of the "overwrite" form (`>`)

Comment: @fatih_koca: WRT the music/sound, I'm not much of a Python guy, but you might try using the full path for your music player in this command: `subprocess.run(["mpg321"],"/home/pi/003.mp3"])`  ; i.e. instead of "mpg321", try `/path/to/mpg321`

Comment: this is not worked. i solved the problem with autostart. thanks for your help. i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem. I created a .desktop file with this code `sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/ses.desktop` then i wrote these lines;

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ses
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/ses.py
```

and

```
reboot
```